# spring-boot jdbc datasource configure?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, spring-data, datasource, spring-jdbc

I ask you to be attentive and indulgent if I express badly my need .
I have to build a multi-base application in spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, rest,java8.
The IT System Department gave instructions to not store logins and password.
usually to build a datasource, we store the url, user and password in the application.properties file or in a config file.
The need as I have evoked has changed.
I have already designed my entities, repositories, services and controllers.
The IT System Department wants to be able to let the administrators to enter the password and the login in the home page (i'm not speaking about spring authentication)

look at this:

```
 @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
     DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
     dataSource.setUrl(url);                        
     dataSource.setUsername(user);//unknown,wait admin to enter this user
     dataSource.setPassword(pwd);//unknown,wait admin to enter this pwd
     return dataSource;
    }
```

Have you ever dealt with this kind of problem?
do you have a specific example (github or tutorial?)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: anyone to give me solution ? plz

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should do:
(1) Provide a web service such as RESTful API to get username/password from the request sent by your home page.
(2) Establish the DB connection based on given URL, username and password.